# Split returning null

Tags: java, null, split, nullpointerexception

Im making game plugin in java and Ive got problem with split function.

```
index = 0;
        int leng = a.length;
        while(index != leng){
            arr = a[index].split("|"); //this is line 158
            if(arr[1] == "blue"){
            blues[index]= arr[1];
            }else{
                reds[index] = arr[1];
            }
            index++;
        }
```

Im getting NullPointerException on line 158.

variable arr is just empty array.

Im printing variable "a" to make sure its not null.
"a" looks like this: 100 58 -9|red.

Can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` receives a regular expression, so instead of `arr = a[index].split("|");`, do `arr = a[index].split("\\|");`

Comment: Ah, took wrong tutorial, there was "-" set as a delimeter.
Im not good with java at all. Thank you

Comment: Also, string comparison is done using `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`, not `==`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that any `a[index]` itself is not null? Array `a` cannot be empty otherwise you wouldn't enter the `while` loop.

Comment: No, Im sure that a is not null

Comment: Not the entire array `a`. I mean `a[index]` which is any one of the elements in the array.